# React Native ScrollView to default position

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I have one Homescreen, with horizontal scrollview witch rendering a flatlist with items. 
I have a drawer menu with some categories. Everytime I'm clicking on menu categories, it's just fetching a data from a server and then render it to the HomeScreen.

When I'm loading a Homescreen first time, scrollview display items as  expected, starting with first item in a left, then second items, 3rd etc..

If I scroll it, let say to the middle of the list, and then open Menu and fetch different data to the same screen, the scrollView is not reseting to initial position, it's still stays in a middle.

My question is how to 'reset' scrollView or flatlist to initial (default position), so when I fetch a new data, it should render it starting from first element from a left, regardless where it was before.

I'll tried to make a ref on FlatList

```
  ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
```

And then in componentDidMount

```
this.flatListRef.scrollTo({ animated: false, index: 0 });
```

But it doesn't work(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.flatListRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.flatListRef.current.scrollTo({ animated: false, x: 0, y: 0 });
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <FlatList ref={this.flatListRef} contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
                ...
          </FlatList>
      );
  }
}
```